# How many cases can draw diagonals that Applicable 2 above condition?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory

Imagine A $n$_regular polygon that vertex is named by $1$ to $n$.

We know can draw $\frac{(n)(n+3)}{2}$ diagonals in $n$_regular polygon and also know if we want draw Maximum diagonals are not intersecting $n-3$.

For example for Flat hexagon we can draw Maximum 3 diagonals that we can do it in $14$ cases.(you can find it easy)

Now imagine draw diagonals that

$1$-any vertex is not connected to $2$ before and $2$ after vertex.

$2$- any 3 vertex is not exist that intersecting two by two in  $n$_regular polygon.

It's not difficult that The Maximum of diagonals can draw is $2(n-5)$.

But the question is how many cases can draw diagonals that Applicable 2 up condition ?

Comment: I'm confused by your wording in the second case. Could you explain "any 3 vertex is not exist that intersecting two by two in $n$-regular polygon?" Perhaps you could give an example where it works and where it doesn't work

Comment: for $n=6$ we can draw $3$ cases that Necessitate this 2 condition .

Comment: if we labeled regular when $n=7$ we have $2(7-5)=4$ diagonals and we can not use this vertexes ${1,4}\{2,5}\{4,7}\{3,6}$ because we ignore the second condition